# Wallet system for React Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm currently setting up an eCommerce platform with React. To make more sales, I want to integrate [eWallet](https://www.iliumsoft.com/ewallet/) so buyers would be able to save money for future purchases and withdraw whenever they want. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please add some specificity to the question?

Comment: I want to integrate wallet system for a React App. I've looked on npm for relevant packages but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** :You can use stripe for payments ie get money to your account
**Step 2**: You should manage customers Transactions in your database
**Step 3** You should catch all the transaction and pass it through the wallet system to give an option to the customer to pay from the wallet

Or

you can use many prebuilt wallet system like [stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/wallets), [paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/) and more